# parametrize value in Locust

Tags: python, load-testing, locust

I need to pass 500 store ids in a load test which will be completing more then millions of transactions. This 500 store ids should be used for this transactions i.e. it will can be repetitive. I am unable to achieve the same

siteId.py

```
sitIDs = ['2', '6']
```

locustfile.py

```
class createrequest:
    def request(self, json_file, name, ssm, my_task):
        self.json_file = json_file
        self.name = name
        self.my_task = my_task

        data = None
        post_headers = {
           
            "content-type": "application/json",
        }

          with open(self.json_file, "r") as myfile:
            data = myfile.read()

        json_data = json.loads(data)
        json_data['headers']['eventId'] = str(uuid.uuid4())

        json_data['data']['pickTaskId'] = str(uuid.uuid4())
        **json_data['data']['siteId'] = sitIDs.pop(0)**
        json_data['data']['timestamp'] = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')[:-3]

        post_headers = {**post_headers, **json_data['headers']}
       
        print(post_headers)
       
        with self.my_task.client.post(
                url="/xxx/xx/xx",
                data=json.dumps(json_data['data']),
                headers=post_headers,
                # params=post_params,
                name=self.name,
                catch_response=True
        ) as response:
            if response.status_code == 202:
                response.success()
            else:
                response.failure("Got wrong response")
```

Error:-

```
worker_2  |     json_data['data']['siteId'] = sitIDs.pop(0)
worker_2  | IndexError: pop from empty list
```

Comment: I think the problem might be using pop since it removes the element from the list. Try using random.choice(sitIDs) since you want it to be repetitive.

Comment: thank you, random.choice(sitIDs) worked for me

Comment: You are welcome.